# How do I change users in Google Keep's chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome, user-accounts, google-chrome-extensions

On the phone I can easily switch between my Google accounts, on YouTube a video can be found that showcases it for the app but this option is just missing for me or has been removed by Google.

Comment: It probably uses the account you're logged into Chrome with. So either use the website or switch Chrome profiles.

Comment: (I don't have enough reputation on this site to add an answer, but here's the correct way to do so...)

The premise is that you want to use multiple Chrome Apps, and not all of them need to be using the same Google account. To do so, add multiple profiles in your Chrome browser for each of the accounts you want to use in those apps. Now, "install" the Chrome Apps within each Chrome profile whose main Google account you want to use within that Chrome App. By doing so, you don't need to logout of all Google accounts. Most Chrome Apps use the main Google account when you simply visit google.com

Answer (score 8):

To switch accounts you have to go to Chrome settings using the 3 bars on the right hand side of the Chrome browser, or the 3 bars on the right hand side of the Chrome app-launcher button.

From there, click on settings and then disconnect your google user. Sign in with the other user account and it'll give you the choice of merging account information (bookmarks, history, etc.) or replacing it.

Shut down the Keep app and re-open it to authenticate to the new user.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It is quite easy with an iphone or android phone. In the App just a swipe will change between multiple accounts.

Now the issue is regarding the Chrome. I am using Mac Chrome 50, but this should work in Chrome on every OS.

Here is what you need to do.

1. Go to settings in your Chrome
2. You will have a default account attached to Chrome when you installed it.
3. It may or may not be same as the one you see on `google.com` with your image in the right corner and when you click that you have option to add account or switch between multiple Google accounts.
4. Simply when in Google settings you will see a column with "People" as the headline.
5. Just click on Add user. You can choose to remove the first one and add the one you need. I have multiple Gmail accounts and want one Google Keep for work and one for my personal tasks.
6. After adding a new user you will now be able to search for Google Keep.
7. You will see two apps just switch between them.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute the keep website app in a window without address box and otther menus.
Press Windows+R and in the Run box enter:

```
Chrome.exe --app=https://keep.google.com
```

Then you can easily switch your Google accounts like on the web app.

More details available here :
http://www.rawinfopages.com/tips/2016/11/run-google-keep-on-the-desktop-in-its-own-window/

Answer (score 0):

For most google apps including Google Keep, you can click on you avatar/image in the top left nav and switch accounts to another google account.

Comment: That's actually not true. I too have the same problem and I easily switch between my accounts on other google products, but in Keep it's just not there... It is on my cell phone though. It's only in my chrome app that it's missing.

Comment: I assume you mean the top right. This is only true for direct access on keep.google.com. From the Chrome app you can't see that.